# Select configuration file on creating WCF proxy instance

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, configuration, wcf-client

Is it possible to create WCF proxy by the given config file, not app.config? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx)**'s a thought